# What am I looking for?

Tags: logical-deduction

What am I looking for?

31EC7E509B5ED4 DE71545E9924CB 2B6A7E9E38FAD8 B316BA4B59F007

*To solve this Puzzle without hints in my opinion is quite hard! But it's not impossible, just tricky. Be aware a hint is always marked **strong** and could be abstract. This text is not part of the puzzle, have fun with it!*

Hint 1:

> 1: **16**

Hint 2:

> 2: **10**

Hint 3:

> 3: **2**

Hint 4:

> 4: **26**

Hint 5:

> 5: **Waterfall**

Hint 6:

> 6: **7 Dimensions**

Comment: If the puzzle is to hard or my hints just to bad / not usefull and the claim is here, I will post the solution as step by step guide with spioler. But I would like to let you guys puzzle first a bit ;)

Comment: Give it some time before you start giving away too many hints or offering to post a solution. There are a lot of time zones that people on this SE come from so not everyone has seen it yet. As for 'hints' if it's something that the puzzle *cannot* be solved without, then it should be part of the puzzle and not a hint. Puzzles should be able to stand on their own without them.

Comment: Your right. I also wanted to wait a while. And the puzzle can be solved without any hints, but as mentioned It would be hard, verry hard.

Comment: But I dont get why the puzzle got downvotes without any information, Is it just because they couldn't solve it?

Comment: Unfortunately not everyone gives a reason why they downvoted, while it is nice to know, it is up to their discretion. It's likely something to do with grammar, or dumping so many hints, or the wording of the puzzle - telling people it's very hard etc. But I don't know for sure since I have not given a DV

Comment: @Anetair I suggest you read: https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1717/167 .

Comment: @awesomepi Read it, but I dont get what you want to say with this. I dont posted just some dumb code. I investigated some time into this puzzle and created it that some guys could have fun with it. I delivered all nessesarcy hints and just said that it would be hard without but not impossible (this is what puzeling means, try and error). I wont deliver a step by step guide in the puzzle it self.

Comment: @n_palum Thanks for your edditings, they are completly valid. As I said "a hint is always marked strong".

Comment: Yes you did. There is nothing in the actual puzzle except a dumb code. This puzzle is impossible without the hints. You may say it's possible, but it's like a puzzle that someone needs to bash for tons and tons of time because  as it's been demonstrated, this puzzle is a lot of different random steps combined. You clearly haven't read the meta post I gave you, because it practically outlines this puzzle.

Comment: "Post a code that’s so hard that nobody can solve it.
Wait a day and post a hint.
Repeat until somebody finally solves it."

Comment: @awesomepi You know the definition of a puzzle? It's puzzle (test of ingenuity) and exactly this is what I posted. By the way I delivered all nessesary hints to solve the puzzle (for guys without ingenuity!), not . For all others the code itselv give you the hints you need. And exactly the way to post hint after hint is dumb as s***. Cause you have to wait for me and I have to put time again and again into it. It spended quite a time into this puzzle to give some guys something to have fun with it, if you dont like, let it be.

Comment: @awesomepi btw ... "Post a code that’s so hard that nobody can solve it. Wait a day and post a hint. Repeat until somebody finally solves it." – awesomepi ... I posted a puzzle with all nessecary hints in a logical order. If you cant solve it I would say your just to bad or not imaginative enough.

Comment: "Yes, it looks impossible to solve without hints.." - Techidiot Why not incorporate the hints into the puzzle instead of posting them seperately then? This is just a badly designed puzzle, but if you're not willing to take feedback, don't ask why there are so many downvotes. At this point you're just being unnecessarily rude. And about the cleverness: many of the people on Puzzling SE are extremely clever, and they know how to solve a good puzzle. This is just a bash your head against your wall puzzle.

Comment: I'm glad to have enjoyed solving (almost all) of this puzzle before seeing all these comments. Ow. I'd be upset too after putting together a twisty puzzle and getting little encouragement. Oh wait, I _was_ upset when that happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the starting line:
 
`31EC7E509B5ED4 DE71545E9924CB 2B6A7E9E38FAD8 B316BA4B59F007`

In the homestretch, but yet to cross the finish line:

> `O PEOPLE, I LOVE THIS WELL BALANCED PUZZLE!`

How’d this get that far?
 
Well, right out of the gate
all those `A B C D E F 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` characters
sure do make it look like
[hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal),
which agrees with Hint 1.

As high-contrast
[binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_code),
though, nothing shouts out:

```
             ..@@...@@@@.@@...@@@@@@..@.@....@..@@.@@.@.@@@@.@@.@.@..
             @@.@@@@..@@@...@.@.@.@...@.@@@@.@..@@..@..@..@..@@..@.@@
             ..@.@.@@.@@.@.@..@@@@@@.@..@@@@...@@@...@@@@@.@.@@.@@...
             @.@@..@@...@.@@.@.@@@.@..@..@.@@.@.@@..@@@@@.........@@@
```

But Hint 2 suggests...

> ...base **10**, which produces four 17-digit
>  [decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal)
>  numbers:

`14052301121216212 62612052008051915 12220516051516120 50409010215120903`

Just to splash around, what would that look like
if it were reinterpreted as hex digits
(and viewed as high-contrast binary,
 wrapping at 56 bits as determined by trial and error ):

```
             ...@.@.......@.@..@...@@.......@...@..@....@..@....@.@@.
             ..@....@..@..@@...@..@@....@..@......@.@..@.........@...
             .....@.@...@@..@...@.@.@...@..@...@...@......@.@...@.@@.
             .....@.@...@.@.@...@.@@....@..@......@.@.....@......@..@
             .......@......@....@.@.@...@..@.....@..@......@@
```

Well!   
Nice alignment, and
a ratio of `.` zeros to `@` ones of 200 :72
that’s just too uneven to be meaningless.
(Random decimal digits interpreted as hex
 would have an uneven ratio of zeros to ones
 as well, but only 170  :102.
 A straight frequency plot of the digits would have revealed the same skew.)
So, from 56-bit lines, how about 8 x 7 blocks?

```
1.  ...@.@..     2.  ..@....@     3.  .....@.@     4.  .....@.@     5.  .......@
    .....@.@         ..@..@@.         ...@@..@         ...@.@.@         ......@.
    ..@...@@         ..@..@@.         ...@.@.@         ...@.@@.         ...@.@.@
    .......@         ...@..@.         ...@..@.         ...@..@.         ...@..@.
    ...@..@.         .....@.@         ..@...@.         .....@.@         ....@..@
    ...@..@.         ..@.....         .....@.@         .....@..         ......@@
    ...@.@@.         ....@...         ...@.@@.         ....@..@
```

Oh.  Perhaps it is 8 bits at a time after all,
with the first 2 bits always 0.
 
So back to...

> ...grouping the “hex” digits in pairs.
>
> ```
>                    14 05 23 01 12 12 16 21 26 26 12 05 20 08 05 19 15
>                    12 22 05 16 05 15 16 12 05 04 09 01 02 15 12 09 03
> ```

That does looks familiar, and not as hex, it seems,...

> ...but as numbers for letters of the alphabet.
>
> ```
>                    14 05 23 01 12 12 16 21 26 26 12 05 20 08 05 19 15
>                     N  E  W  A  L  L  P  U  Z  Z  L  E  T  H  E  S  O
>
>                    12 22 05 16 05 15 16 12 05 04 09 01 02 15 12 09 03
>                     L  V  E  P  E  O  P  L  E  D  I  A  B  O  L  I  C
>
>                 =  NEW ALL PUZZLE THE SOLVE PEOPLE DIABOLIC
> ```

Now Hints 3 and 4 make complete sense,
and add up to 7 words at that.

Some rearrangement produces:

> `SOLVE THE ALL NEW DIABOLIC PUZZLE, PEOPLE!`

But that has a misspelling,
and a slightly more liberal rearrangement produces:

> `O PEOPLE, I LOVE THIS WELL BALANCED PUZZLE!`

I still suspect that some other rearrangement lies ahead.
Perhaps Hints 5 and 6 and another nap (or a kind bystander?)
will help untangle the finish line.

Comment: Mhh the question Is how mutch help do you want? From the view of the hints it seems that you are on a good way, also the results proof you right. But the answer is not tickt  as correct so you should know what this means. Tell me if you want a hint more or just a little input to what you already have.

Comment: Thank you, @Anetair, I've been fascinated by the **7**-ness of this puzzle, beginning with the **7**x8 original hex digits, then the **7**x8-bit wrap that almost accidentally revealed a pattern, and hint 6 of course. I hope that something **7**-ly will occur to me, or a bystander, before needing Hint **7**. (And yes, I'm also looking forward to Hint 5 hitting home too.) Not at all bored yet

Comment: Hahah I'm happy you like it. So I won't deliver you a hint, that you can have the fun to solve it. But just to say I dont delivered a step by step guide.

Comment: I like the mix here, @Anetair. Just like some crossword clues, some of my favorite hints are those that only make sense looking back at them, like Hints 3 & 4 already.

Answer (score 1):

### **Partial**

Yes, it looks impossible to solve without hints..So, going with that -

**Hint 1**

> Looks like we need to treat it as Hex.
>  31EC7E509B5ED4DE71545E9924CB2B6A7E9E38FAD8B316BA4B59F007

**Hint 2**

> Converting it to Base 10 gives - 
>
>  5257590040812640764761519568719461501880149126052777795398496022535

**Hint 3**

> Converting to Base 2 gives -
>  11000111 10110001 11111001 01000010 01101101 01111011 01010011 01111001 11000101 01010001 01111010 01100100 10010011 00101100 10101101 10101001 11111010 01111000 11100011 11101011 01100010 11001100 01011010 11101001 00101101 01100111 11000000 000111

**Hint 4**

> Converting to A1Z26 gives -
>  SI QG XI 66 JI LC 83 LA SG 81 LB J0 NG 44 QC PI Y0 L0 VG WE 98 TD 90 WC 45 JC SB G

No idea about the next step ...

Comment: As I already said, you could sit a verry long time on this puzzle without any hints, but for the crazy guys under us this is maybe the right thing. To your solution I can say its wrong :) So if you dont want to puzzle longer on your own, I have the following small hint for you: The first step Is always the hardest.

Answer (score 0):

As per the hints, it should be:

> hex (16) to decimal (10) to binary (2) [Why just not convert directly?]
> to A1Z26 (26) to Vignere / Substituion Key / Playfair "Waterfall"
> and something with 7 dimensions – I have no idea.

Comment: Maybe you asked yourself the right question, be aware the hints dont have to assosicate. Please cover your solution steps for others, that there are no spoilers.

Comment: @Anetair: Are you saying that Alex is on the right track?  Or are you just trying to decrease the signal-to-noise ratio?

Comment: He startet good, but as I said he maybe asked his self the right question. I dont want to ruin the puzzle for him, if he needs more help I could help him.